# How to do an unit test in yii2 advanced?

Tags: php, yii2, phpunit, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I know how to run it with codeception,  but I don't know what I have to put on the code bellow. Someone can help me please.?

```
protected function setUp()
{
}

protected function tearDown()
{
}

// tests
public function testMe()
{
}
```

[image]